# Family=scat in mgcv not behaving as expected

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, heavy-tailed

I am analysing the eye-tracking data of an experiment in psycholinguistics I ran some time ago, and after fitting a model that captures the data pretty well, I ran a number of model checks and found that the residuals were not normally distributed but exhibited heavy tails. I followed the advice of a number of tutorials on how to apply GAMMs to the study of language and cognition (as well as the mgcv manual) and fitted this model with 'family=scat' in order to capture the distribution of the residuals.

However, things look much worse in the new model: the tails appear somewhat staggered now and the statistical summary is very different indeed, with some edfs turning to negative values, and some F-values and Standard Errors to 0.

I'm not quite sure what is going on here and I would really welcome any information or indeed advice as to what might be happening and/or what checks or further analyses I ought to look into. I include below a sample of the dataset, the code for the best fit model, the relevant QQ-plots, and the statistical summaries pre- and post-family=scat. Thanks in advance!

The dataset looks like this, where AOI is the main predictor and stands for areas of interests, with 4 such AOIs, and empirical logs (elogs) constitute the dependent variable along with their weights.

[image: Dataset]

The best-fit model is the following (note the 'event' smooth; I'm not including a correction of the autocorrelation of the data, which is common in eye-tracking studies, in order to simplify the presentation, but this works well here):

m5 <- bam(Elogs~AOI + s(Time, by=AOI)
+ s(Time, Event, by=AOI, bs="fs", m=1),
data=FRO1data, discrete=TRUE, weights = 1/Weights)

The QQ-plot for this model looks like this:

[image: QQ-plot for m5]

And this is the summary of the statistics:

[image: Stats m5]

If I add family=scat to the model, the QQ-plot looks like this, followed by the statistics summary.
[image: QQ-plot for m5S]

[image: Stats m5S]

Comment: The staggered look suggests a mixture distribution;ie, clusters of observations. Such phenomena can be modelled using an indicator variable if you can discover the source; otherwise a mixture model can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BigBendRegion, and apologies for the late response (I hadn't seen it); it is much appreciated indeed. Are there any references/sites I could look at in order to understand what the issue is (and to fix it)? As it stands I remain as lost as before. Thanks in advance!